# Calling a register method from 2 or more controllers best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I don't want to repeat myself. That is, I don't want the same code in two different controllers.

I always start from a default mvc5 web app project. That project has a `Register` ActionMethod in an `AccountController`:

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Say I have a `CampaignController` and I want to register a user when he/she is on that page, fills out his/her username and pass and clicks the send form/submit button. What is the best thing to do in the ActionMethod of that form/controller?

Yes, I want to have the registerform in two or more places.

What is the best way to accomplish this in mvc 5?

Comment: Tried this and the more code I move over to the base class from the AccountController the more code I need to move over since there is so many dependencies. I thought that maybe, instead of moving code to a base class, why not make the entire AccountController class as the base controller class? Good? Bad?

Comment: Hmm the first comment by somebody seems to be gone now(?) (about moving code to a base class).

Answer (score 0):

Create a logic layer

put the register logic in that logic layer

add the logic layer as reference in the web layer

hit the function in the logic layer from both actionresults :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example at least... I would call the actions of your AccountController from your Campaign views.

Answer (score 0):

For me it working like a charm after setting the current ControllerContext to AccountControllerContext

```
//This is employee controller class
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EmployeeId,FirstName,LastName,DOJ,DOB,Address,City,State,Mobile,Landline,ReportsTo,Salary")] Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AccountController accountController = new AccountController();
            accountController.ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext;
            //accountController.UserManager;
            var userId = accountController.RegisterAccount(new RegisterViewModel { Email = "temp@temp.com", Password = "Pravallika!23" });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                employee.UserId = userId;                    
                employee.CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }                
        }

//customized method in AccountController
    public string RegisterAccount(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };                
            IdentityResult result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
            //to add roles
            //UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return user.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed
        return null;
    }
```